# RavenDb JavaScript JS Client Create Database

Tags: javascript, ravendb, ravendb4

Is it even possible to check if a database exists and then create one if it doesn't, using the NodeJs RavenDb Client?

I've got as fair as this (*index.js*):

```
const mainStore = DocumentStore.create(URLS.database, 'main');
mainStore.initialize();
mainStore.operations.send(new CreateDatabaseOperation(new DatabaseDocument('main')));
```

But I get this error:

> ue: Max topology update tries reached

There is little documentation on the capabilities of the NodeJs client, it doesn't even look like the repository is active....